# Stuck with: Any finite sequence of $0$s and $1$s will happen in infinite sequence of Bernoulli Trials

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

I have been looking at the following problem for a while and nothing comes to mind. I tried looking at the complement of the event in question below but that did not seem to help either.
**Problem:** Let $0 < p < 1$ and suppose that $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with success probability $p.$ Let $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k$ be elements of $\{0,1\}$. Show that
$$P(\text{there is an }n \geq 1\text{ so that }X_n = a_1,X_{n+1} = a_2,...,X_{n+k−1}= a_k) = 1.$$
Could anyone please give me a hint on how to get going on this problem, or some intuition that elucidates it?
A million thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Borel-Cantelli lemmas (in particular the second one) could be of use here. You have an infinite sequence of independent (if you choose the sequences to be non-overlapping) sequences of length $k$, each of which matches the sequence in question with probability $>0$.

For more intuition and justification, see the [Infinite monkey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem).